# Reality Composer – How to change shadow opacity?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm a visual artist and I was using Adobe Aero to bring my VR drawings into AR. Recently I found out about Reality Composer and will definitely switch now because of the people occlusion. The only problem I have is, that I want my shadows to appear darker, similar to Aero (right now they are very weak).

I tried to do all kinds of stuff but couldn't find a solution. I heard that it could maybe be possible with coding but I unfortunately can't code. Does anyone know how I could achieve that?

[image]